# When running SonarQube 5.3 in AWS missing rules after reprovisioning pointing to same Postgres RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, sonarqube, amazon-rds, sonarqube-ops

We have SonarQube 5.3 installed in AWS as a single instance auto scaling group pointed at a Postgres RDS database.  When the instance gets destroyed a new instance is automatically stood up and Sonar is installed on the new instance pointed at the database and started back up.

When this happens the rules are missing (Rules tab has not rules, saying no language plugin is installed) but the analysis history is there.  There are no indications in the logs that there is an issue.  If we stop Sonar and configure the in memory database and restart the rules return.  Then we configure it back to using the Postgres RDS instance and restart everything seems fine.

What could we be doing wrong when standing up the new instance that prevents it from loading the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The default plugins packaged with the distribution are installed only the first time, when database is fresh. When connecting to an existing database, the plugins stored in the directory extensions/plugins/ are loaded. In your case this directory is empty. You should be careful that this directory is up-to-date, as well as conf/ and data/ too.